# Sending multiple objects in Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, post, razor, model-view-controller, textbox

I'm trying to send multiple objects via FormMethod.Post, but the problem is that only the value of the first one is saved and the value of second one is the same as first. The problem is probably in the Razor syntax which I'm pretty new at, here is the code I'm using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("chAdress", "Adress", FormMethod.Post))
{
      @Html.Label("Number")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Number)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number)

      @Html.Label("Distance")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Distance)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Distance)

      @Html.Label("New Number")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model1 => model1.Number)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model1 => model1.Number)

      @Html.Label("New Distance")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model1 => model1.Distance)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model1 => model1.Distance)
      <button type="submit">Change Adress</button>
 }
```

And here is the controller that should make the change:

```
public void chAdress(Adress model, Adress model1)
{
            prepareConnection();

            string distance = model.Distance.ToString();
            string newDistance = model1.Distance.ToString();

            Dictionary<string, object> queryDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            queryDict.Add("distance", distance);
            queryDict.Add("newDistance", newDistance);

            var query = new Neo4jClient.Cypher.CypherQuery("start n=node(*) where (n:Adress) and exists(n.distance) and n.distance =~ {distance} set n.distance = {newDistance} return n",
                                                            queryDict, CypherResultMode.Set);

            List<Adress> adrese = ((IRawGraphClient)client).ExecuteGetCypherResults<Adress>(query).ToList();
 }
```

After running in debug mode, I see that the value of distance is always the same as the newDistance, what is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: You are using the same model property for both Distance and New Distance. `TextBoxFor` generates the "name" attribute which is used in the form submission.

Comment: you can't submit two separate objects like that, or have two models in your view, for that matter. Make a class which contains 2 properties which are each instances of Address, and make that class your model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views can only be typed to one model. You appear to be trying referencing a Model and Model1 in your view. You should create a new ViewModel to contain all properties that you want to return from your form and then, if needed, process that from your controller into the distinct objects you need.

Since you actually have just one model (but are trying to use it like 2) you are overwriting the properties of the previously set values.

Comment: There are not two models. As you even say yourself you cannot do that so how would it work at all? The lambda parameter can be named anything: "model", "model1", "mickeymouse", it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, he's trying to use two models and by virtue of the way he's doing it, referencing one model and overwriting a previous property. I'll edit my answer to better add this.

Comment: It appears that creating the new ViewModel was the best way to solve this, that worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

POST method will always use the property name to submit the data. Event though you have 2 different models but still it has the same property name which will always get overridden by the latest property value which is new newDistance in this case. Either add a new property name newDistance to model like model.newDistance or create a different model with property name as newDistance like model1.newDistance.